# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - changes on entity Iframe - unsaved notification

Tags: iframe, dynamics-crm, entity, crm, microsoft-dynamics

we have some custom Iframe on entities - when content of iframe is changed (user fill some data). and user is leaving changes, there is no notification, that there were made some changes. (no change on unsaved icons)

Is there some possibility to notify user, that there are unsaved changes?

One of my idea was to add hidden field on entity form and when there is some change in Iframe, trough javascript change value on this field. This is tested and working, but maybe there is some better way to do it.

Comment: what you are doing currently is good way. What you could also do it keep an Boolean variable in your Js and set that to true false depending on condition you could set notification. But issue would be you will not know if the Iframe is left, I would say the way you are doing currently seems to be better way.

Comment: Auto-save: other option is "save the changes" if you don't want to notify them.

Comment: @petrtim Hi i am facing the same issue. Could you please tell me how to detect the change in iframe? what is the event that helps understand that a value is changed in the iframe
Please suggest.